# xlwings create AutomationServer Object

Tags: pywin32, xlwings

I have an xlwing app that currently connects through Excel VBA (called in xlwings) to an xll-based Add-In to logon and refresh data.

This works fine, but I now would like to get rid of the Excel-part and move it to xlwings.

This is the VBA I'm using:

```
Sub LogonAndRefresh()
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean
    Dim CognosOfficeAutomationObject As Object
    Dim Reporting As Object
    Dim invokeAddin As Object

    Set CognosOfficeAutomationObject = Application.COMAddIns("CognosOffice12.Connect").Object.AutomationServer
    Set Reporting = CognosOfficeAutomationObject.Application("COR", "1.1")
    Set invokeAddin = Reporting

    CognosOfficeAutomationObject.SuppressMessages True
    bSuccess = CognosOfficeAutomationObject.Logon("https://server.net", "domain\user", "password", "CAM_name")
    bSuccess = CognosOfficeAutomationObject.Logon("https://server.net", "domain\user", "password", "DB_name")
    CognosOfficeAutomationObject.SuppressMessages False
    
    If (bSuccess) Then
        CognosOfficeAutomationObject.ClearAllData
        CognosOfficeAutomationObject.RefreshAllData
    End If
End Sub
```

I can with xlwings:

```
for addin in app.api.COMAddIns:
    print(addin.description)
```

and:

```
test = app.api.COMAddIns('CognosOffice12.Connect').Connect
```

returns True

but i think the issue is with .Object.AutomationServer:

```
test = app.api.COMAddIns('CognosOffice12.Connect').Object.AutomationServer
```

returns an error:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'CognosOfficeInterfaceAddin12', 'AutomationServer object only available on a STA.', None, 0, -2146233088), None)

Any suggestions or examples how this could be done?

Comment: So I am guessing STA stands for 'Single Threaded Apartment' ie the Object won't be reliable for multi-threading. You may need to go to the underlying pythoncom/win32com library to choose how to initialize COM. AFAIK Excel is by default a single-threaded execution model. Perhaps post your full python code. With win32com you can explicitly choose the COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED threading model, which might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows/win32/descriptions-workings-ole-threading-models